# Ajax instant messaging (web-based)

Tags: ajax, instant-messaging

Just wondering: Would it be acceptable to start some simple Ajax instant messaging (web-based) for a large social network service (considering thousands of registered users)? I am new to this, so I'm just wondering. What if to check for a new message every two or three seconds?

Edited: Could a plain shared server handle so many requests every so often? And yes, I would roll my own program.

Comment: what do you mean by "would it be acceptable"?

Comment: Your question is a little vague...  Are you trying to create an application like Facebook Chat or Meebo or ??  Do you have a backend chat server that you are trying to integrate to, or are you trying to roll your own?

Comment: "Edited: Could a plain shared server handle so many requests every so often? And yes, I would roll my own program."

It depends on usage.  "Thousands of registered users" isn't so many, but if half of them are actually using the chat regularly and all at peak hours, you would likely have a problem on shared hosting.

As to rolling your own -- do you really want to do this?  Check out the options for XMPP clients alone at http://xmpp.org/software/clients.shtml#web .  XMPP is a logical protocol to use for instant messenging and should be simpler than creating your own.

Comment: By "check for a new message every two or three seconds" I hope that you don't mean polling every single online user to see if they have new messages. Make the clients send messages to the server, not the server request if the clients have new messages.

Answer (score 1):

There're many web im client based on standard XMPP protocol. You could try [iJab](http://code.google.com/p/ijab/) or [JWChat](http://www.jwchat.org).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to write your own, unless you have some unique requirements, but whether the server can handle this largely depends on the server language and webserver setup, as to how well it scales.

You will need to do some heavy load testing, to ensure that the high load that is expected will work, as your traffic will be very heavy. For example, if your social networking site is soccer related, then during the World Cup you may expect to see more traffic than Wed mornings.

If you asked the question with:

1. I want to use language X.
2. I want to use webserver Y.
3. I am using this framework for the
   webservice.
4. I would like to accept voice
   recordings and webcam recordings
   over IM, as well as text.

How well will this scale on my one 1GHz server?

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to make a peer-to-peer (P2P) browser-embedded chat, than even a shared hosting will do for dozens of thousands of simultaneous users :) :)